# Recursive Fibonacci in C, using fork()

Tags: c, recursion

Up front, I readily admit this is homework. But I have been banging my head against the wall on this one and I just don't get it. Assignment parameters are as follows: "Recursively compute the specified number. If print is true, print it. Otherwise, provide it to my parent process.

NOTE: The solution must be recursive and it must fork a new child for each call. Each process should call `doFib()` exactly once."

This is my first experience using fork(), and though I think I understand, I just cannot wrap my head around why I'm not getting the correct answer. Here is my code, which is fairly rudimentary:

```
doFib(int n, int doPrint)
{
    int status;
    int print;
    pid_t pid1;
    pid_t pid2;
    int sum1;
    int sum2;

    if (n < 2)
        exit(n);

    pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        doFib(n-1, doPrint);
        exit(n-1);
    }

    pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        doFib(n-2, doPrint);
        exit(n-2);
    }

    while ((pid1 = waitpid(-1,&status, 0)) >0)
    {
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
            sum1 += WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }

    while ((pid2 = waitpid(-1,&status, 0)) >0)
    {
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
            sum2 += WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }

    print = sum1 + sum2;

    if(doPrint)
        printf("%d\n", print);
    else
        exit(0);
}
```

Fibonacci is one of the first examples of recursion I was taught, and I understand it at a base level. However, when I run my program, with 10 as the given argument (though any argument produces incorrect results), I get a stream of junk ending in: `-1861761537` (there are lots of these negative numbers), 17. Any changes I make result in different junk values, but still end up at 17.

I believe the problem is in my use of waitpid, but I don't know what it would be. Am I correct in assuming this is the source of my error? I've scoured the textbook, man pages, Internet, etc. and I don't know what I could fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you indent you code properly.

Comment: Usage of recursion is discourage in production code. See for example NASA guidlines: http://lars-lab.jpl.nasa.gov/JPL_Coding_Standard_C.pdf

Comment: Glad they are calculating finincci numbers **recursively**; because teaching students that **`O(2^n)`** code is acceptable will definitely set them up for success later in life.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation problems -- I'd never posted code on Stack Overflow before. Unfortunately, I don't have a choice; the solution MUST be recursive and MUST use fork. The assignment is silly at a base level, but my frustration stems from whatever element of waitpid I'm not getting. (Unless there's an obvious error in the recursion I'm not seeing.)

Comment: @awashburn Well, `O(phi^n)`, but point taken. As long as they learn the memoization stuff though, things shouldn't be too terrible.

Comment: @DennisMeng If I am not mistaken, it is exactly bounded (from above and below) by ***`Θ(φ^n)`***, but observing the recursive algorithm runs in ***`O(2^n)`*** is immediately obvious. I find the ***[fork-bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)*** potential much more disturbing. Heaven for bid a curious student *tests* his code with a large input value on the university shared server... *The assignment reeks of poor forethought!*

Comment: @awashburn: Teaching these kinds of algorithms is not uncommon. They teach basic recursion and how to solve recurrences (which is really important for the study of algorithms), and starting with mergesort is not the best. Besides, there are concepts there that are vital at the time of designing algorithms. Teaching does not mean being practical, it means teaching hard-to-grasp concepts as pedagogically as possible.

Comment: Did a rollback so that we can actually see what the original question was. However, the original poster did mention that he plans on working out the problem on his own.

Comment: I know it's often necessary to introduce a new concept using an example which may not be best practice in production code, but honestly, trying to teach `fork()` by calculating successive Fibonacci numbers in separate processes is one of the most egregiously bad examples I've seen.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: if the purpose is to teach pattern transformations (asynch for synch), not fork, then i think it's a great example.

Answer (score 3):

You used `+=` assignment instead of `=` assignment when assigning values to `sum1` & `sum2` from `WEXITSTATUS()`. Because `sum1` & `sum2` were never initialized, this created an insertion vector for garbage data into your program.

Also as [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zack) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795811/recursive-fibonacci-in-c-using-fork/18796237#comment27718615_18796237), 
the code will not work on a Unix machines for values `n >= 15` due to an exit status max value of `255`.

Comment: This makes sense logically, but in execution it gave me an output of 375. Something is running FAR too many times.

Comment: @MartyEischeid yes my initial test lead to what appears to be arithmetic overflow... Something is still amiss...

Comment: Well, I found one problem: the second while loop isn't being entered at all. I'm currently testing some fixes to ascertain why that would be.

Comment: I don't know if this is the actual problem or not, but you can only reliably use 0 through 127 as exit codes.  (Many but not all systems permit 0 through 255. I have never seen a Unixy system that allowed a larger value.)

Comment: @Zack I beleive you are correct. I tried incrementally calculating values using this program. It correct produced `fib(14): 337 == 144 + 233`, but failed producing `fib(15): 354 != 233 + 337`. I assume it is because, as you pointed out, `337 > 255` and cannot be an exit status. Also `354 = 233 + 337%256`.

Answer (score 1):

i'll take a stab at this:

```
 exit(n-1);
```

why are you decrementing the input as the exit value? if i'm reading the intent of the code correctly, the exit value is supposed to be the intermediate result

## Addendum

:) Since this is homework, i won't give you the answer. Also since I don't know the answer, not having used fork() in...a very long time.

Instead, think about the answer as a pattern substitution:

1. The first pattern is a normal recursive Fib function, with synchronous calls
2. The second pattern is retrieving a result from asynchronous forks instead of synchronous calls

Write the first pattern and test it, then transform it with the second pattern. There are at least two correct solutions. Find both.

Comment: Then the current "n" of the process is the value I want to exit on? The recursive calls would then be handling the "n-1" and "n-2" cases. A quick test of making both exit statements read "exit(n)" produced a similar stream of junk which ended on 20, which is at least closer to the desired 55, though I may be misreading your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is debug your program. I'd suggest start by giving it a simple execution path and see what it does. For example start with n=1, then n=2, then n=3. Comment out the 2nd fork code and concentrate on getting the first part working. Make use of print statements to inspect values of variables at different points in the program - which will give you clues as to how it is working, or not.